# querySourceFeature returns empty array

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I am using mapbox to try and query all features of the mapbox tileset and return them as geojson. From what I understand, to query features that are no visible on the screen, you must use querysourcefeatures. My tileset only shows up at zoom 14 so I am having trouble querying all the features in the dataset at once and then applying a filter. Is this possible? It stills like querySourceFeatures returns an empty array.

```
function addLayers() {
    map.addSource('plutonew-c03oxi', {
        'type': 'vector',
        'url': 'mapbox://samtpr.4ehwzn0r'
    });

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "parcels_fill",
        "type": "fill",
        "source": "plutonew-c03oxi",
        "source-layer": "plutonew-c03oxi",
       'layout': {
            'visibility': 'visible'
        },
        paint: {
            'fill-color': 'blue',            
            'fill-outline-color': 'gray',
            "fill-opacity": ["case",
            ["boolean", ["feature-state", "hover"], false],
            0.5,
            0
            ]
        }
    });

var features = map.querySourceFeatures('plutonew-c03oxi',  {filter: ["==", ['get','ZIPCODE'], zipcode_val]});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From what I understand, to query features that are no visible on the screen, you must use querysourcefeatures

You may have misunderstood. `querySourceFeatures` allows you to query features that are present within the vector tiles currently loaded and displayable within the current viewport and zoom level. Unlike `queryRenderedFeatures` they don't have to actually be rendered through a visible layer, however.

In this case it sounds like you're hoping to gain access to features that are not available at the current zoom level, which is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Steve. I find the explanation of the two very confusing in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, thank you, missed this little bit in the docs "This function does not check tiles outside the currently visible viewport."